# Blazor Shared Library assets not available in startup

Tags: configuration, blazor-webassembly, assets

I have a Blazor WASM Application and a additional Blazor Class Library. My goal is to put a settings.json in the BlazorClassLIb/wwwroot folder and access that from the Server and from the Client Application.

The Razor files can reference the assets without any issue like this:

```
<link href="_content/BlazorClassLib/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

When I try to do this in my server App:

```
var fileName = "_content/BlazorClassLib/settings.json";
configurationManager.AddJsonFile(fileName);
var settings = configurationManager.Get<Settings>();
services.AddSingleton(settings);
```

it fails with file not found.

I managed to do it like that ( not cool, but it works)

```
var fileName = = Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "..", "..", "BlazorClassLib", "wwwroot","settings.json")
```

I can not find a solution in my WASM-Client.

Is there a fix so I could use the _content/BlazorClassLib syntax? If not, how can I navigate to my classlib?

Comment: Create a class on BlazorClassLIb to load appsettings and return all values by properties. on other projects you can access this class to load and read all values.

Comment: @mRizvandi I tried that, but that is not working. In Blazor Wasm, these files are not downloaded along side the assets referenced by .razor files / html files.

Comment: Also you can use embedded resource to add appsettings to your client WASM project and access them by resource class.